# Is there a way to manage Github Forks

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I am trying to find good forks of some github repositories and i can't seem to find a way to do so, other than go through the list of forks one by one to determine if they have added more commits and what are the commit messages that they used (to know what features they fixed or added).

this is an arduous task especially when most of the forks are old or are the on par with the original repo.

Is there a software that would help organize these forks and help manage them ?

Comment: You could build a program to do this, using the github api: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-forks

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the Insights Network feature for this. It shows me a list of all forks and any branches that have changes over time. You can easily see recent commits that might be interesting to look at:

[image]